# Calculation function returns 0 whatever the user puts in after creating header files

Tags: c

im buisy learning myself c with more or less not having any previous programming exprerience.
I have made a simple program in c and it worked more or less. Its not perfect or anywhere near that but its just fine for learning.

But now i got a bug in my program and i can't find it nor do i know how to properly bug track such a thing (yet).

I actually use github to also get to learn that and perhaps you guys can see what i did wrong in the function or with the headers. (The thing is that i currently try to understand how header files work in C.)
And this also teaches me to make propper commits :/ .....

https://github.com/Greendweller/MyFirstProgram

the bug is that the program wil not calculate anything anymore. It accepts the user input but just shows 0 for a result and i cant figure out why.
The calclation functions are in ../circle/circlefunctions.c

I hope this will be enough information or that i need to post the code here. So please let me know.

**edit**
okay so i have to post the code directly, no problem:

circlefunctions.c

```
#include "circlefunctions.h"
#define PI 3.14

float   diameter;
double  radius;
double  surface;
double  outline;

void circle_functions()
{
    radius   = diameter / 2;
    surface  = PI * (radius * radius);
    outline  = 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

circlefunctions.h

```
extern float  diameter;
extern double radius;
extern double surface;
extern double outline;

void circle_functions();
```

main.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include "menu/menu.h"
    #include "circle/circlemenu.h"
    #include "circle/circlefunctions.h"
    #include "input/input.h"



    int main(void)
{
    while(1)
{
    menu();
    switch(menu_user_input())
{
    case 1:

        info_top();
        cir_user_input();
        circle_functions();
        info_bottom();
        break;

    case 2:
        system("cls");

    case 3:
        system("cls");

    case 9:
        system("cls");
        break;

    case 0:
        return(0);
}

}
 return 0;
}
```

input.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "input.h"

int menu_user_input()
{
    int number;
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    return number;
}

float cir_user_input()
{
    float diameter;
    scanf(" %e", &diameter);
    return diameter;
}
```

input.h

```
int   menu_user_input();
float cir_user_input();
```

i can post the rest if needed but i guess this will be enough?

**edit2**

I think i found a/the solution:

i set the variable diameter 2 times. in input.c and circlecalculations.c and that resets the value i think. 
Or just left blank as input.h was never included in circlecalculations.c.

Comment: Please post the code directly, rather than posting a link to the code.

Comment: Added as requested. My apollogies.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using global variables, which is (almost) always a bad design.  Your current calculation function:

```
void circle_functions()
{
  radius = diameter / 2;
  surface = PI * (radius * radius);
  outline = 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

Much better would be to pass in the needed inputs and return the result:

```
double circle_functions(double diameter)
{
  double radius = diameter / 2;
  double surface = PI * (radius * radius);
  double outline = 2 * PI * radius;
  return outline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for tht advice. I will keep this in mind and read more about that.

Comment: After reading up about this:  i use those variables in other parts in the program to print those values in the console. Im a bit lost on how to get those values if they aren't global?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following line of code:

```
cir_user_input();
```

...in which you're ignoring the return value of cir_user_input.

Instead you should be using:

```
diameter = cir_user_input();
```

...because the other functions expect the global variables to be set.

However, you are overusing global variables. I would consider restructuring your code to not use global variables.

Comment: Thank you for the info. you tip led me to a bugfix . And ill look into those global variables..